# How do I determine what a Crystal Reports function does?

Tags: sql, function, crystal-reports, formula

I have a custom crystal report which retrieves invoices from a database. There is a formula in the report that has the following code:

```
V6AttachmentsGetAttachment ({Command.AttachmentID},{?ReportAttachmentChannel} )
```

From my understanding, the formula has a function called 'V6AttachmentsGetAttachment' which takes two parameters (the first is a report field and the second is a report parameter).

This calculates a dynamic hyperlink.

How can I determine how exactly this is calculated? I am trying to figure out if I can replicate this calculation in SQL.

Is `V6AttachmentsGetAttachment` something that is stored in the SQL database? I can not find any references to it in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could either be a custom function or one contained in a user-function library (UFL).

**Custom Function**

- Edit a formula (any formula will do)
- Assuming that it is a custom function, it will be listed below the Report Custom Functions node:

[image]

**UFL**

If this function is contained in a user-function library (UFL), you should see it listed in the Function tree:

[image]

u252000.dll contains a single function `DateTimeto2000()`.

If this is the case, then you will need to locate the source code for the UFL.

Comment: There is nothing in this node.

Comment: I found it! It is a COM and .NET UFL. 

What does this mean?

Comment: See http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2009/05/22/creating-crystal-reports-user-function-libraries-ufl-with-visual-studio-net

Comment: I regasm crufle.dll and cruflv6.dll as assemblies.  I need to give them a strong name and add them to global cache.   Can you help

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom function created by Viewpoint Construction Software (V6).  It is used to connect with Construction Imaging, a document management system, to return images of things like invoices.

I believe the custom function is available if you have the Viewpoint client installed.

Answer (score 0):

CRUFLE and CRUFLV6 are viewpoint dlls.  They are registered as global access controls using regasm.  Crystal reports can then access the functionality within the dll.

https://support.viewpoint.com/s/knowledgedetail?c__urlname=Issue-109356-Error-when-running-crystal-reports-via-remote-access-not-VRL-UFL-u212com-dll-or-u2lcom-dll-that-implements-this-function-is-missing

CRUFLE and CRUFLV6
file version 22.2.0.716

I use crystal reports 2016, 32 bit

1. I downloaded the 32 bit crufle.dll and cruflv6
2. I copied the crufle.dll and cruflv6 to C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86
3. %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe crufle.dll
4. %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe cruflv6.dll

regedit and search for the crufle and cruflv6 ensuring there were no other versions register.  The u2lcom.dll error message was misleading because the dll is loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86.   you can see u2lcom.dll is loaded in the crystal report about-> more info which shows the loaded modules.

dumpbin will show that u2lcom.dll is loaded and availabe

dumpbin /EXPORTs u2lcom.dll

Section contains the following exports for U2LCOM.dll

```
00000000 characteristics
5A54B943 time date stamp Tue Jan  9 05:44:51 2018
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
      15 number of functions
      15 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      3    0 00005670 InitPerThread
      4    1 00005680 IsThreadSafe
      5    2 000056A0 UFCallCOMFunction
      6    3 000056C0 UFEndJob
      7    4 000056F0 UFErrorRecovery
      8    5 00005720 UFGetFunctionDefStrings
      9    6 00005730 UFGetFunctionExamples
     10    7 00005740 UFGetFunctionTemplates
     11    8 00005750 UFGetVersion
     12    9 00005760 UFInitialize
      1    A 00005610 UFSetPreferredViewingLocale
      2    B 00005630 UFSetProductLocale
     13    C 000057E0 UFStartJob
     14    D 00005810 UFTerminate
     15    E 00005860 UninitPerThread
```

Summary

```
    1000 .data
    1000 .gfids
    4000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
    8000 .text
```